# Quasar: Why is QCheckbox selected all in QTable?

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, quasar

I check only one `checkbox`, but all of the other `checkboxs` are also checked. It seems like all `checkbox` has the same `index` or `id`, however, there is no way to figure out to fix this issue. I have googled, but could not find the way I am looking for.

Here is the code I wrote

**QTable**

```js
         <q-table
          id="selection-table"
          :title="undefined"
          :data="curData"
          :columns="columns"
          @request="updateTableData"
          :rows-per-page-options="[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]"
          :pagination.sync="pagination"
          :loading="isLoading"
          row-key="name"
          class="no-shadow q-pa-none"
          selection="multiple"
          :selected.sync="selected"
          :selected-rows-label="getSelectedString"
        >
          <template v-slot:body="props">
            <q-tr :props="props" class="q-pa-none">
              <q-td>
                <q-checkbox v-model="props.selected" />
                {{ props }}
              </q-td>
              <q-td
                v-for="col in props.cols"
                :key="col.name"
                :props="props"
                class="q-pa-none"
                row-key="name"
                :auto-width="col.name == 'title' ? false : true"
              >
                <span v-if="col.name === 'title'">
                  {{ props.row.title }}
                </span>
                <span v-else-if="col.name === 'status'">
                  <span v-if="col.value === 0">... </span>
                  <span
                    v-else-if="
                      col.value === 200 && props.goodsStatusCode === 11
                    "
                    >...</span
                  >
                  <span v-else>
                    <span class="text-red">...)</span>
                  </span>
                </span>
                <span v-else> {{ col.value }} </span>
              </q-td>
            </q-tr>
          </template>
        </q-table>
```

**Script**

```js
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'SelectionTable',
  data() {
    return {
      selected: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getSelectedString() {
      return this.selected.length === 0
        ? ''
        : `${this.selected.length} record${
            this.selected.length > 1 ? 's' : ''
          } `;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Would you let me know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone needs this I have figured out what was missing.

What I needed to changed was this:

```js
row-key="name"
```

to

```js
row-key="_id"
```

since literally `row-key` means the `key` or `id` of the row I select.

Hope this would help someone like me!